# Synchronous Call outs from Standard Pagelayout In Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

There is a requirement to make synchronous call out from standard page lay outs of salesfore say for eg. standard case layout. As of my knowledge we can not make a synchronous call out in context to a standard page layout. As process builder or workflow or js button everything will work in an asynchronous context. Want to confirm that , please help with your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm... no?

Process Builder, Workflow Rule, Trigger - they all fire on event (insert, update). They're all synchronous (the whole operation waits for them to finish saving). Just viewing a record doesn't count as an event. I think you're confusing the "what triggers the action" and "what kind of action happens". Try to distinguish the two. It's like workflows - a workflow rule (condition to be met) is one thing and then what happens (field update, new task, email, outbound message) is completely different thing.

From "clicks not code" functionality Outbound Messages and emails are asynchronous - but as I said above - just viewing a record doesn't count as update, nothing will fire. Callouts done from apex (and you have several options discussed below) can be either synchronous or async. So it's whatever you want really.

---

You might look into:

1. a Visualforce page which you'll embed on the page layout (either directly or as a Chatter action for example). That page's apex controller could do the callout.
2. Or maybe you'd be able to do it in VF from JavaScript (without apex) - make a REST call to your url, process results... There are tons of code samples how to integrate Google Maps for example, this wouldn't be too different.
3. or (bit of future thinking) make a Lightning Component. You'll be able to embed it in the Lightning App Builder (the "better" page layouts) directly. in Classic SF you'd have to make it a Chatter Action or use "Lightning Out" to reuse a component in a VF page and embed that instead.
4. Bit more advanced (and paid extra) would be to use Salesforce Connect a.k.a Lightning Connect. Try to pass the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_connect), easier than explaining it here. You could end up with related list of external records under the case and user wouldn't even realise this data is not hosted in SF. [Connect requires OData compatible data source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_adapters.htm&type=5) or a [piece of Apex that acts as adapter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_examples.htm) and pretends to return valid format.
5. If it's about Cases - maybe you can do something fancy using the Service Cloud Console. You'd have to experiment a bit but maybe one of side panels could be a VF page or `<iframe>` to another system. Maybe you could make something happen with Macros...

Comment: Thank you very well crafted answer.